# Header resizing not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-chrome

I am using the immensely Theme from Themeskingdom with a fixed navbar. When scrolling downwards the navbar should resize to a smaller state.

Firefox and Safari both are working fine, tested on OSX.
In Chrome the Logo is disappearing or is showing some space after scrolling back to top.
I made a [video](http://youtu.be/a4reQ-Tnm68) to show the issue.
The Developer tested the site and said it has to be a problem with my Chrome Browser. But a friend of mine gets the same problem after visiting the site with chrome.
Seems like the script is not loaded.

Is the site working fine with your system? If so why is it not working with my Chrome.
Heres the [Site](http://web646.fge1.5hosting.com/fuchsbau/fuchsbau2014-wp/)

Comment: provide relevant code in question

Comment: Works for me chrome 32 XP. If I scroll fast, the whole bar gets obscured a few times

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with Chrome 32 (Windows 7).

I think your problem is related to a specific version of Chrome. I suggest you to contact back the Developer, and tell him what specific version you're using. Thus, he will (probably) be able to reproduce the problem, and solve it.